# Android Emulator not working for Alarm Reminder program

Tags: android, android-emulator, alarmmanager

I am new to Android. I have tried an sample application for status bar reminder for mentioning date. But it is not working in Emulator, i don't know what i am missing. I have attached the sample code here

Main.java

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);               
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 8);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1,alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

In the alarm receiving class i have the following code

AlarmReceiver.java

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 NotificationManager nm;
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 CharSequence from = "Raja";
 CharSequence message = "My First App...";
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(), 0);
 Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
 notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
  nm.notify(1, notif);
  }
 }
```

In the manifest file i have added the following line (before the application tag close) for Alarm receiving class

```
  <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Log cat entries

```
    03-28 00:11:18.411: I/ActivityManager(69): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.raja.sample/.Main } from pid 556
03-28 00:11:18.481: I/ActivityManager(69): Start proc com.raja.sample for activity com.raja.sample/.Main: pid=564 uid=10036 gids={}
03-28 00:11:18.491: D/AndroidRuntime(556): Shutting down VM
03-28 00:11:18.512: D/dalvikvm(556): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 319K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
03-28 00:11:18.552: D/dalvikvm(556): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-28 00:11:18.571: I/AndroidRuntime(556): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-28 00:11:19.352: I/IMFO(564): RAKAAAAAAAAAAAAA
03-28 00:11:19.611: I/ActivityManager(69): Displayed com.raja.sample/.Main: +1s147ms
03-28 00:11:20.101: W/InputManagerService(69): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4061d080 (uid=10035 pid=532)
03-28 00:11:24.751: D/dalvikvm(247): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 54% free 2544K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 97ms
03-28 00:13:28.577: D/SntpClient(69): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(), 0);
```

You are passing a blank Intent here . Change this to the intent of Activity you want to all, for example :

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(context,MyActivity.class), 0);
```

Try the following Activity:

```
public class TestAlarmActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     // get a Calendar object with current time
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "O'Doyle Rules!");
        // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get the AlarmManager service
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000, sender);
        Toast.makeText(this, "tii;;; inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and the following Broadcastreceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private NotificationManager nm;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         CharSequence from = "Raja";
         CharSequence message = "My First App...";
         PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(), 0);
         Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
         notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
          nm.notify(1, notif);
    }
```

I think your alarm is not getting executed because **it has already passed** as you are passing day of month as 25

Comment: Hi Akhil, what you mean by MyActivity.class ? Is that MainActivity or Alarm receiver Activity? I tried both the class, its saying the error "The constructor Intent(AlarmReceiver, Class<Main>) is undefined"

Comment: MainActivity is the Activity you want to open when the user clicks on the expanded notification. I just put a name since I dont know the correct name of your activity. You can put that activity's name, also change "this" to "context".  like new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);

Comment: Akil, thanks. After replacing context that error disappered. But still i am not getting the Notification in the top bar. ( i have updated the class names in my question)

Comment: put  a toast as the first line of onReceive(), check if you are able to see it. your code for notification look ok. Also post your log cat if you see any warnings/errors

Comment: I am not getting the Toast message :( Here is the log cat messages from starting the application   


03-27 23:42:47.689: D/AndroidRuntime(668): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm

03-27 23:42:48.038: E/InputDispatcher(66): channel '4074eaf0 com.raja.sample/com.raja.sample.Main (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8

03-27 23:42:48.038: E/InputDispatcher(66): channel '4074eaf0 com.raja.sample/com.raja.sample.Main (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: 03-27 23:42:48.058: I/WindowManager(66): WIN DEATH: Window{4074eaf0 com.raja.sample/com.raja.sample.Main paused=false}
03-27 23:42:48.819: D/PackageManager(66):   Activities: com.raja.sample.Main
03-27 23:42:51.539: D/AndroidRuntime(682): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-27 23:42:51.578: I/ActivityManager(66): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.raja.sample/.Main } from pid 682

Comment: 03-27 23:42:51.729: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.raja.sample for activity com.raja.sample/.Main: pid=691 uid=10036 gids={}
03-27 23:42:52.808: I/ActivityManager(66): Displayed com.raja.sample/.Main: +1s91ms

Comment: let me check and get back to you.. mean while change cal.getTimeInMillis() from am.set() to  System.currentTimeMillis()+ 7000 to try your b receiver

Comment: Akil, Thanks for your info. If i put System.currentTimeMillis()+7000 this code working fine. But receiver invoked after 7s, not in the specific time. (which i mentioned in calendar)

Comment: baecause you mentioned the data which is already passed. Give it a future data and time, it should run. Also please upvote and approve the solution as it is working..

Comment: Akil, thanks for your reply. I need 15 reputation to upvote. Actually your information are really useful. & already i tried to change the date, the above code is only for reference. anyway thanks for your info